# is it possible to size images for mobile on a simple HTML site?

Tags: html, mobile-website, image-size

I have a very basic HTML website with images displayed with the following code:

```
<center><img src="style/images/istress.jpg" height="400" width="400" alt="photo by Kristin" class="attachment" /></center>
```

Is it possible to also optimize the images for mobile? Currently they are stretched/skewed when I visit the site via Safari mobile browser. Not sure if I'm able to set another size with just HTML.

Comment: Instead of HTML width atribute, use CSS - `img{max-width:400px;width:100%}` ->  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jK8Nu/)

Comment: You may like to read up about CSS @media queries. It's very interesting.

Answer (score 0):

Use the GD library to provide multiple sizes, even on the fly if you want to be fruity :)

There are several methods of optimizing image sizes from dynamic resizing to heavy compression and I will leave this to you to investigate, good link for some light reading is:

http://salman-w.blogspot.co.uk/2008/10/resize-images-using-phpgd-library.html

If you are not massively technically capable you could use http://www.imgix.com/ which I have used on a few occasions. Quite reliable too.

Comment: thanks for the information! I've not ventured into the land of PHP or programming languages yet but that article is very interesting!

Comment: Edited my answer to include a link to imgix which is probably more what your looking for. You could use there system as a model for your own and with a little trial and error is not too hard to do.

Comment: looks like their Retina Displays option is what I'm looking for - well a cheaper option would be nice. thanks for the follow up! still wading through pages of CSS/PHP info